# How to rotate the preview image from FileUpload and save it to the database

Tags: javascript, c#, rotation, image-rotation

I am trying to display an image on my website using input file and what I want to do is to have a button that will rotate the image in 90/180/260/360degree while it is in a runtime. Once rotated, there will be another button for saving the image into the database with it's proper rotated orientation. Here's my code snippet.

the html

```
    <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server"/>
   <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
      <Triggers>
          <asp:PostBackTrigger ControlID="btnGenerate" /> 
      </Triggers>
       <ContentTemplate>
        <asp:Image ID="Image1" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/Images/NoUser.jpg" style="height: 200px;max-height: 200px; max-width: 100%;" class='north'/>
        <br />
        <input ID="inputFile" runat="server" type="file" name="file" onchange="previewFile()" />
        </p>
        <asp:Button UseSubmitBehavior="false" ID="btnRotate" runat="server" Text="rotate" OnClientClick="return rotatefunction();" />
        <p>
         <asp:Button ID="btnGenerate" runat="server" OnClick="btnGenerate_Click" Text="Generate" />
        <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label>
         </ContentTemplate>
         </asp:updatepanel>
```

the JavaScript and CSS where I'm rotating the image during runtime

```
<style type="text/css">
        .north {
            transform:rotate(0deg);
            -ms-transform:rotate(0deg); /* IE 9 */
            -webkit-transform:rotate(0deg); /* Safari and Chrome */
            }
            .west {
            transform:rotate(90deg);
            -ms-transform:rotate(90deg); /* IE 9 */
            -webkit-transform:rotate(90deg); /* Safari and Chrome */
            }
            .south {
            transform:rotate(180deg);
            -ms-transform:rotate(180deg); /* IE 9 */
            -webkit-transform:rotate(180deg); /* Safari and Chrome */

            }
            .east {
            transform:rotate(270deg);
            -ms-transform:rotate(270deg); /* IE 9 */
            -webkit-transform:rotate(270deg); /* Safari and Chrome */
            }
     </style>
     <script type="text/javascript">
         function previewFile() {
             var preview = document.querySelector('#<%=Image1.ClientID %>');
             var file = document.querySelector('#<%=inputFile.ClientID %>').files[0];
                var reader = new FileReader();

            reader.onloadend = function () {
                preview.src = reader.result;
            }

            if (file) {
                reader.readAsDataURL(file);
            } else {
                preview.src = "";
            }
         }

         function rotatefunction() {
             var img = document.getElementById("Image1");
             if (document.getElementById("Image1").classList.contains('north')) {
                 document.getElementById("Image1").classList.toggle('west');
             } else if (document.getElementById("Image1").classList.contains('west')) {
                 document.getElementById("Image1").classList.toggle('south');
             } else if (document.getElementById("Image1").classList.contains('south')) {
                 document.getElementById("Image1").classList.toggle('east');
             } else if (document.getElementById("Image1").classList.contains('east')) {
                 document.getElementById("Image1").classList.toggle('north');
             }

             return false;
         }


    </script>
```

saving to database

```
protected void btnGenerate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        HttpPostedFile file = inputFile.PostedFile;
        Stream inputStream = file.InputStream;
        BinaryReader binaryReader=new BinaryReader(inputStream);
        byte[] bArr = binaryReader.ReadBytes((int)inputStream.Length);

 try
        {
            SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("Data Source=192.168.100.108;Network Library=DBMSSOCN;Initial Catalog=express;Integrated Security=False;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=user;Password=pass1234;Min Pool Size=5;Max Pool Size=100;");

            conn.Open();

            SqlCommand addbill = new SqlCommand("sp_add_image", conn);
            addbill.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

            addbill.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", "1");
            addbill.Parameters.AddWithValue("@file", SqlDbType.Binary).Value = bArr;

            //try
            //{

            addbill.ExecuteNonQuery();
            conn.Close();
            //}
            //finally
            //{
            //   conn.Close();
            //  }

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            //log.log("Error" + ex.Message + ex.StackTrace);
        }

    }
```

what I'm getting into the database is the original orientation of the image and not the rotated one. Can someone please help me regarding to this, I can't find a way on how to rotate the image properly and get its right orientation. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

First, You have to upload original. Save Your rotation value in some Session (for example: 0-0deg, 1 for 90deg, 2 for 180 deg and 3 for 270deg).

Then, when You hit `btnGenerate` create new image rotated by choosen value.

`
//get the path to the image
    string path = Server.MapPath(Image1.ImageUrl);

```
//create an image object from the image in that path
System.Drawing.Image img = System.Drawing.Image.FromFile(path);

//rotate the image
img.RotateFlip(RotateFlipType.Rotate90FlipXY);

//save the image out to the file
img.Save(path);

//release image file
img.Dispose();`
```

This is example for rotating image for 90deg.
Then use Your code, load new rotated image, save to db and delete both images (original and rotated one).

Comment: How will I get the image from that sample code so I can convert it to byte array and saving it into the database?